# Need advice on how to move forward with self-build conservatory

Tags: exterior

I recently bought a self-build conservatory. It is to be built on the foundations of a previous conservatory so the sides, foundations, frontage, and drainage are all there to begin with. Myself and my father bought it as a joint project, I was going to do most of the physical work while my father would take care of the technical side of things (he used to be a builder).

The problem is my father has had a stroke and is therefore unable to oversee the project so I need to get someone in to help erect the various bits of conservatory in line with the specifications. I don't think its a difficult job but I will need someone to help me. So my question is who could I get in to do this and how much do you think it could cost?

Apologies if this question is a little basic but this is my first home improvement project.

Comment: The cost side of this is beyond the scope of this site, but if I was in your shoes, I'd first try to absorb as much of the instructions from the manufacturer as possible. Absent useful instructions, there are probably youtube videos of similar projects. If you still feel daunted, find a good builder and explain that you're looking for a bit of hand-holding and go from there. I'd look for someone like your father -- age-wise, experience-wise, and quite possibly a solo operator.

Comment: It really depends on the scope of the project. You may get by with any hired hand, a 'handyman' or perhaps you may need an actual contractor or someone that does actual framing. Cost is also completely dependent on the scope of the project. Ultimately, you need to talk to some local people and get local estimates.

Comment: At the very least I'll need someone to help with the physical side of things. After all I doubt I can put the Conservatory up myself. But, also I think I'll see if I get someone in who has done this sort of thing before as I have zero experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a nice [time lapse video](http://www.floriangreenhouse.com/monarch_example_page.html) of our DiY conservatory going up. What's *not* shown were all the 'difficult' parts.

Unless you can find someone like Aloysius mentions, you'll need to straight up contract this out, as DA01 says. No contractor that <strike>I know</strike> *use* would let you just strap on a safety harness and start glazing some windows.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll have to have a look around and see if ther

Comment: There is anyone available that can help.